# Is that possible to have a sliding panel?

Tags: windows-phone-7, components, slidingdrawer

I am developing an application in wp7, the application is already been developed in android and iPhone.

Both uses a component sliding panel as they are default in it, now for the same appearance am supposed to use the component gives the same look and feel.

Is that possible to use any combination of components OR any customized dll available for that component OR is there any alternated equivalent component available for this sliding pannel.

The sliding panel i expect is like this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q6x9za4MZY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is very simple, just use [popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) with custom [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx).

> ```
>       DoubleAnimation anima = new DoubleAnimation();
>         anima.From = //current position;
>         anima.To = //slider position;
> ```

```
        //animation now proportional to pixel difference

        anima.Duration = new Duration(System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Abs((300))));
        //Debug.WriteLine("Duration=" + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Abs((to - from) * 2)));
        // Set attached properties
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anima, m_Popup);
        //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima, new PropertyPath(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.WidthProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima, new PropertyPath(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.VerticalOffsetProperty));

        // Create storyboard, add animation, and fire it up!
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(anima);
        storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Can i slide it stick with finger. Like it comes up and down along with the finger, just like the android default sliding drawer in the launcher.

Comment: you have slider in windows phone,you just have to watch for it.

Comment: do you point this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202877(v=vs.92).aspx

This is what am using now. What i need is - I need this click and drag this storyboard instead of one start animation.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.aspx mate it's just an idea, i'm not sure if it's gonna work, but i think is worth the shot

Comment: Popup is still not hardware accelerated - you'll instantly have worse perf if you use it.